# foreach loop causing blank entries?

Tags: java, jstl

I have this code which iterates through `ArrayList<String> towns = new ArrayList<String>();` using JSTL but I keep getting alternating blank entries (every 2nd row) even if the ArrayList does not show any blank entries, so I'm not sure whats going on.

```
<c:if test="${!empty towns }">
    <select id="town">
        <c:forEach items="${towns}" varStatus="loop">
            <option value="${towns[loop.index]}">${towns[loop.index]}<option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `</option>` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:if test="${!empty towns}">
    <select id="town">
        <c:forEach var="t" items="${towns}">
            <option value="${t}">${t}<option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</c:if>
```